# Answering a question when the only acceptable answer is a video

Tags: discussion

The answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254978/does-the-fallout-4-1-03-patch-fix-the-glitches-related-to-infinite-building) was deleted.

The question clearly states that proof is needed. There was no other way to show proof than to actually show it with a video.

The video shows all 3 items required for acceptance in one continuos shot:

1. Proof that version 1.03 was installed
2. Proof that the unlimited resources glitch still works
3. Proof that the unlimited build capacity glitch still works

Here is my answer:[image]

Screenshots are out of the question since a malicious user could fake them. It's also hard to see a glitch with a few screenshots.

The only other option would be to say "yeah I tried it and it works", but I wouldn't accept such an answer since this doesn't prove anything.

If videos are not allowed to exist as complete answers and a video is the only way to prove an answer, then perhaps the entire question should be deleted as well?

Comment: a) RE: Images being faked: Videos can be faked too, it's harder but can be done b) You can inline/embed YouTube videos by just pasting the raw link (http not https) c) That video title is awfully click-baity IMO and doesn't necessarily reflect the content that it contains, but hey, we aren't the YouTube police :-P. d) But having said all that I don't think the answer should've been deleted. You should definitely merge the list you gave in this meta into the answer as it accurately describes the contents of the video.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback. I incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: If you haven't already, flag the answer for undeletion once you have improved it. I'd vote to undelete it but it has been deleted by a moderator and only a moderator can undelete it.

Comment: As a sidenote, a request for proof, while possible, isn't something answerers have to provide.  It'd be *nice*, but it comes off feeling like you've already got an answer in mind, and you're just asking the question so only you can answer it.

Comment: @Frank I think that works for most cases but not all. Trust was essential for this question since upgrading a version is irreversible. Most other answers on Arqade are in a video game world where the user can try again. I put in a lot of work that I didn't want to risk losing it from blind faith. It's pretty obvious that I didn't know the answer. Even if I did, there's nothing wrong with answering your own question when it adds to the knowledge base of this site.

Comment: I'm not saying it is. But we don't have exceptions for special questions. There is no way to require proof.

Comment: This gets extra tricky, because if I am reading it right, it's your question and your answer. We generally assume good faith and don't require proof - in this case, you risk it seeming like you are requiring proof so that you could select your own answer. There are other ways, as people mentioned, to build trust here, like rep etc. Not saying that this was asked with bad intent, just pointing out that this is an unusual case that we really don't run into often, so we don't have a set rule.

Answer (score 6):

1. An answer that contains only an externally hosted video can not be a good answer.
2. Deleting answers that contain nothing but links to externally hosted content is appropriate to ensure bad answers don't become the norm.

> the only acceptable answer is a video

This can only be if the question specifically asks for a video-only answer However this would mean that the question asks for a bad answer, since one of the definitions of a [good answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) is:

> Provide context for links
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

YouTube videos are external content.

Owners of monetized channels of course prefer to require watching their video. Deleting video-only answers is appropriate to ensure external-content-only answers don't become the norm.

Comment: I like this answer. At the same time, can you think of any alternatives to a video that elicit the trust needed to follow the requested answer in the example? While it has been mentioned by @Robotnik that videos can be faked just like screenshots, a video is safer to trust since it is more difficult to do. In other words, what's better than a video in this case?

Comment: @kraftydevil - on Arqade, a person's rep points should be a good indicator of someone's trustworthiness. Unfortunately this gives the impression to a lot of new users that we're elitist, when we are only scrutinising their work more closely because we don't yet trust them enough. That isn't to say that someone with 10K rep doesn't need to show their work or give references, but it means you can generally trust that they aren't doctoring images or making facts up.

Comment: @Robotnik - yeah I get that for sure - In this example there was at least one answer with a member having over 2K rep (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/255021/43379). The problem is that the particular answer did not show the member's firsthand experience. That means the trust was in the hands of the content itself. I trust that the poster thinks the answer is true - but that doesn't make it true. All sorts of things sneak into releases without being publicly declared.

Comment: @kraftydevil you are making up a problem. As for the deletion of your post: The problem visible to me is not that a video is present, the problem is that the answer post doesn't contain the answer but only links to it. You can **write** the answer and then use the video as "proof" and then it will be fine.